# how to separate identity rows with one column being different

Tags: sql

I am trying to separate identity rows which has two different values in a column.

For example my data set looks like this:

```
PID   pdate     col2   source    col3
------------------------------------------
100   20210616  AAA    source1     12
100   20210616  AAA    source2     10
500   20210616  YYY    source1     null
500   20210616  YYY    source2     70
500   20210616  YYY    source2     45 
220   20210616  BBB    source1     98 
220   20210616  BBB    source1     aa
666   20210616  PPP    source1     19
336   20210616  MMM    source2     40
```

I want to separate rows which has same PID, Pdate, col2 for source source 1 and source2.col3 can be random. For PID 500, there are three rows. However, I would like to keep just two rows (source1 and source 2) and another row with this ID will be separated.

I would like to have output:

Output 1:

```
PID   pdate     col2   source    col3
------------------------------------------
100   20210616  AAA    source1     12
100   20210616  AAA    source2     10
500   20210616  YYY    source1     null
500   20210616  YYY    source2     70
```

Output 2:

```
PID   pdate     col2   source    col3
------------------------------------------
500   20210616  YYY    source2     45 
220   20210616  BBB    source1     98 
220   20210616  BBB    source1     aa
666   20210616  PPP    source1     19
336   20210616  MMM    source2     40
```

I tried with row number, however with this all 3 rows with PID 500 fall under output1.

```
SELECT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY PID, Pdate, col2) AS RNo, 
    Pdate,
    col2
FROM
    table1
ORDER BY
    PID, Pdate, col2
```

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: You've specified two seemingly separate outputs/result sets.  Do you want 2 different queries, or just 1 query?

Comment: Yes .. two different queries..

Comment: I assumed , if I get first one right , then I can do not exist and take out the second output .. however , two queries is fine too..

Comment: Is there a column here which provides the ordering for choosing 2 records from each group at a time?  We really need such an ordering in order to answer your question.

Comment: Nope. We do not have . I wanted to create a row number which can group the rows with same columns and different source.